# put_flash without redirect or render?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a form for users to enter in information. I want a message to pop up if it was added successfully or not (no page redirect, like an AJAX call). The problem is that a Plug.Conn.NotSentError error comes up

template:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, foo_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_input f, :email, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= submit "Subscribe!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <p><%= get_flash(@conn, :info) %></p>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Thank you!")
    {:error, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "An error occurred.")
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to rerender the form after putting the flash, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`put_flash/3` appends a flash message to the connection. The connection is used for the reply. In your case there is no reply. You need some kind of reply to transfer data (including the flash message) back to the client.

If you just want to append a flash message to the current site, people usually render the same thing again (usually the page contains a form). `render conn, :new`

The other possibility is to use either ajax or channels for a smoother experience. In the case of ajax you can use javascript to display the message. In phoenix you can render any string to give an appropriate response in your controller. So you'd say `text conn, "your text, which can be json or not"`. See the documentation [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#text/2).
Then you can use jquery to display your flash message and make the request. Check [their doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for how to do that. You probably want to use the .done callback for that.

The third option (channels) is not something, I'd recommend for this task unless you have many of these forms.